# UIButton settitle dynamically change

Tags: ios7, uibutton

I have a uibutton and I am changing its title to a data that I am receiving from webservice I have printed the uibutton current tile and the title I want to show but its not changing the button title

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[status objectForKey:@"detail"] valueForKey:@"goalDetailText"]];
[goalButton setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateSelected];
NSLog(@"title is %@ and value is %@",goalButton.currentTitle,str);                [goalButton setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

console is

```
2013-11-25 12:13:04.666 = sdad [3389:1003] title is Loading ... and value is Learn and practise how to minimize "emotional eating"
```

but the problem is the uibutton title is taking time to change the title like a loong time, but I have checked the value from webservice is not null and its printing absolutely fine but the settitle is taking too much time. my project is on IOS7.

Answer (score 0):

If your button state changed to normal, after you tapped up inside, you need to use `UIControlStateNormal` status for title:

```
[goalButton setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```